# How to print a linked list in Java?

Tags: java, list, adt, tostring

I'm desperately trying to get my linked list printed but to no avail. Searching the net I found that a tostring method is required, but I still cannot make it work.

Here is the code I use for my reference based linked list:

http://pastebin.com/M4PvKcZ8

and http://pastebin.com/nCbwa06d .

How can I print my linked list items????

Note: The linked list is not empty, I just posted the part of the code that is needed for you to help me.

Comment: Why not using `LinkedList`?

Comment: Show us what you have tried to print it, what did not work in your attempt?

Comment: @Michael Most probable. Why would anyone re-implement the weel? I mean, common! This is `LinkedList` without Generics.

Comment: Why the downvotes? It is really important to implement your own `LinkedList` and `ArrayList` once in your live, or you would maybe never know in which situation you better use which list. (in terms of read/write performance)

Answer (score 1):

You need to Override `toString()` on both classes: The list and the item. Then, inside the `toString()` method of your list, you are iterating over your elements, calling `toString()` on every child.

example for the list:

```
@Override 
public String toString(){
   StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
   builder.append("ReferenceBasedList[");
   ListNode currentElement = head;

   while (currentElement != null){
      builder.append(currentElement.toString());

      currentElement = currentElement.getNext();

      //seperator if required:
      if (currentElement != null){
        builder.append(", ");
      }
   }

   builder.append("]");
   return builder.toString();
}
```

Also it is common practice to add the hashcode at the end of each element, to easily spot if 2 references are pointing to the same object when printing them.

Comment: Nice one without recursion. You could use a `StringBuilder` dough.

Comment: Yes, Stringbuild would be the better choice.